# How to find elements in ASP sources using selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, asp-classic

```
<frame name="top" src="../LoginOrder/announcements.asp">
<frame name="bottom" src="../LoginOrder/menu_bar.asp" scrolling="no">
```

The content in those two frames is just asp source so I can't find element in those two frames using normal FindElement methods of selenium.

So is there any way I can find those elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locate the desired frame and switch to it using `switchTo()`. Example in Java:

```
WebElement frame = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("frame[src*=announcements]"));
driver.switchTo().frame(frame);
```

Here we are checking for `announcements` text to be present inside the `src` attribute of a frame.